# Conditional property for typescript type/object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a recipe ingredient type that looks like this

```
export type RecipeIngredient = {
  name: string;
  quantity: Number | string;
  measurement: "grams" | "mililitres" | "custom";
};
```

Example

```
const potatoes: RecipeIngredient = { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 100, measurement: 'grams' }
```

which is fine, but I also want to have the quantity as a string **only** when the measurement is custom. Is this possible?

Correct example

```
const rosemary: RecipeIngredient = { name: 'rosemary', quantity: 'a handful', measurement: 'custom' }
```

What I want to be invalid

```
const fish: RecipeIngredient = { name: 'fish', quantity: '100g', measurement: 'grams' }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export type RecipeIngredient = {
  name: string;
  quantity: Number;
  measurement: "grams" | "mililitres";
} | {
  name: string;
  quantity: string;
  measurement: "custom";
};
```

Comment: Easy but problem is when we want to use that variable, we need to manually cast. for e.g. `const custom: RecipeIngredient = { ...,  measurement: "custom"};` Now when I use it somewhere, just for example, `processIt(custom.measurement as 'custom');`

Comment: Well, union type is more useful for annotating function params. For your case I would just let TS infer the type of custom from value instead of annotate it.